# Permissions tab is disabled for the owner

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, security

I am the owner of an SP online site and the permissions tab has been disabled for me.
[image]

Url of the above page is:

https://Tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/_layouts/15/user.aspx?obj=%7BIDDDDDD%7D,list&List=%7BIDDDDDD%7D

but I can still add users to the documnet library through the right-hand side menu as shown below:
[image]

I do not know how this has happened or how to fix the issue.

It seems that I can manage the groups in SP designer 2013 as well
[image]

Can it be due to ShortPoint SPFx? it seems I cannot remove it as there is no remove button for it:
[image]

Comment: Is the URL of the page shown in your screenshot https://<siteurl>/_layouts/15/user.aspx ?

Comment: Yes, it is @Allen_MSFT

Comment: From the given URL: https://Tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/_layouts/15/user.aspx?obj=%7BIDDDDDD%7D,list&List=%7BIDDDDDD%7D, is it the permission page of a list? And from the screenshot, it seems that you have stopped inheriting permissions in the list, right? Do you have appropriate permission to the lsit? Also change a browser to have a try.

Comment: It is the permission of a list, I have also tried Edge and Chrome, it did not work in any of them, everything was fine, but not sure what has happened that caused the tab to be disabled, it has happened today.  Yes, I stopped inheriting permission while the tab was working about a month ago, but the tab was working until yesterday.

Comment: The permissions tab of library document has been also disabled as well

Comment: Can be due to some issues with the masterpage, I was working with it in SP desinger 2013 but I am almost sure that I did not change anything

Comment: Thanks for your questions, they triggered my mind to find the issue, still not sure why, but reseting the masterpages solved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to reset MasterPages to site definition in SP designer,

[image]

and it seems the problem has been solved.

Comment: It also solved the problem of showing the "remove" button for removing Shortpoint SPFx

Comment: You can mark your answer if this issue has been resolved. It will be beneficial to others in this forum who meet similar issues to yours. Thanks for your contribution :)

Comment: thanks for the reminder, completely forgot to do this